# Two views in screen+Augmented rality+iphone

Tags: iphone, augmented-reality

I want to implement the `Augmented Reality` with layer
Example like this:-http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b64_16K2e08

i had used to locate the place by using this:-`https://github.com/zac/iphonearkit`

Now the i want the circle which shows the small view of the other screen.

how can i get the other circular view on the screen.

provide the sample code if anyone have.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if yo exact want to use this kind of thing first you need to register and create some layars on the layar they also provide some tutorials and demo how to create and integrate them in ios apps you can get them from their web sites.When you register there you will get all kind of stuff to implement these kind of things .

Thanks,